# How to use dates in the yahoo_fin Python Package

Tags: python

I recently installed yahoo_fin and I tired the following example:

get_calls('NFLX' ')

It worked. I then tired the following:

get_calls('NFLX', '11/8/2019')

It failed. Here is what I got:

get_calls('NFLX', '11/8/2019')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    get_calls('NFLX', '11/8/2019')

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\options.py", line 48, in get_calls
    options_chain = get_options_chain(ticker, date)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\options.py", line 32, in get_options_chain
    tables = pd.read_html(site)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 906, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 743, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

ValueError: No tables found

I am using version 3.6.3 of Python and I am also using Spyder.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you think I have found a bug?

I updated my version of yahoo_fin. Not really sure it was out of date. I now get the following error messages when I run the command: get_calls("nflx", "1/31/20")

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    get_calls("nflx", "1/31/20")

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\options.py", line 48, in get_calls
    options_chain = get_options_chain(ticker, date)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\options.py", line 32, in get_options_chain
    tables = pd.read_html(site)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 906, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 743, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

File "C:\Users\rsher\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

ValueError: No tables found

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you have it.

```
from yahoo_fin.options import get_calls

get_calls("nflx", "1/31/20")
```

Are you using the most recent version of [yahoo_fin](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/)?  It should be (as of this writing) version 0.8.4.  Another possible issue is that there could have been a problem with Yahoo Finance's page for that option chain at that particular time.